# How to select subject from an auto complete option?

Tags: selenium, xpath, autocomplete

Website link- https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form/

I am trying to find xpath for an auto suggested option for Subject field
[image: anan]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of interacting with that dropdown:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
actions = ActionChains(browser)

url = 'https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form/'
browser.get(url) 

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "subjectsInput"))).send_keys('m')

elusive_el = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".subjects-auto-complete__menu")))
print(elusive_el.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
maths_option = elusive_el.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Maths']")
maths_option.click()
print('selected maths')
```

This should select the Math option, and also print in terminal the html structure of that element, so you can inspect them, and eventually select other child elements as well - you will have to send another string into that input field, wait for the dropdown to initialize, select another option.

Selenium docs: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
Its working fine now I am able to select Maths

Answer (score 1):

HTML of required element is

```
<div class="subjects-auto-complete__option subjects-auto-complete__option--is-focused css-1n7v3ny-option" id="react-select-2-option-0" tabindex="-1">Maths</div>
```

Try this one

```
//div[contains(@class, "subjects-auto-complete__option")]
```

Comment: Subject field xpath (//input[@id='subjectsInput']) I got it but after entering the text I am unable to select it from the auto populate list.

Comment: @SwastikaNarayan that's because you need to [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for auto-complete option to appear and become clickable

Comment: @SwastikaNarayan actually if to enter "Math" into input field I  don't even need to wait... `driver.find_element('xpath', '//div[contains(@class, "subjects-auto-complete__option")]').click()` works fine

Comment: After adding wait it is working fine now 
Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to find xpath for the 'subject' field to select multiple options.
I am able to send the text, but not able to select it from the dropdown.

Here is my code:
`driver.findElement(By.id("subjectsInput")).sendKeys("M");` driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Maths']")).click();
`Thread.sleep(1000);
Suggest me where I went wrong.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the [markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so your answer can be formatted in a way that others can understand.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33300230)